# Trying to use COALESCE and Cast Together to numeric Column

Tags: sql

```sql
CAST(COALESCE (S_ID, 'UNASSIGNED') AS VARCHAR(20)) as ID
```

Casting a column to varchar as its numeric column. and trying to replace null with unassigned using coalesce.
But still having error of incosistent datatype.

Comment: Just swap the order you are doing things. `COALESCE()` likely needs all arguments to be the same data type: `COALESCE (CAST(S_ID AS VARCHAR(20)), 'UNASSIGNED') as ID` This is a guess though as you didn't share what RDBMS you are working on and some databases may be more forgiving in their implementation of `COALESCE()`.